# Sending a value from opened form 2 to form 1

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Sorry, I know this question, or similar has been asked frequently, but as I've gone through different threads, I just don't know how to apply it to my program.

Here's my situation:
In Form 1, I have a label. There's a button that opens Form 2, which has radiobuttons and a button. The button in Form 2 should send a string value from the radio button, to the label.Text in form 1. How can I go around in doing so?

So, below is what opened form 2.

```
private void selectkeyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectKeyboard sk = new selectKeyboard();
    sk.ShowDialog();
}
```

And in Form 2, here's what i have so far:

```
public Form1 otherForm = new Form1();
string hotkey = "";

public void hotkeyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    RadioButton rr = (RadioButton)sender;       
    switch (rr.Name)
    {
         case ("buttonF1"):
             hotkey = "F1 ";
             break;
    }            
}

public void buttonConfirmKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     hotkey = otherForm.keyLabel.Text;
     this.Close();
}
```

Where I have `public Form1 otherForm = new Form1();` 
and `hotkey = otherForm.keyLabel.Text;` I found it [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6525896%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396/)

And it doesn't seem to be working, as when I press the button on form2, the form closes but the label in form1 doesn't change...

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: How is it that the other questions haven't given you what you need? It's a common mistake to instantiate a new form rather than refer to the original. You're creating a new form in the code `public Form1 otherForm = new Form1();`. You need to pass a reference from your original `Form1` to the new `Form2` instead.

Comment: Instead of setting the label directly from form2, It's better to use the result of form2. So you can `ShowDialog` your form2 and if the result is `DialogResult.OK` use seleted value (that you should store it in a property in form2) to set the label text in form1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches to do this. You could go like this :

> Solution one:

*(Don't forget to set the modifier for you label1 in this case to Public. You can set this in the designer options > under Properties > design)*

**Form 1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

**Form 2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1 _parent;

    public Form2(Form1 parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parent = parent;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _parent.label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

> Solution 2

*Instead of setting label1 to public, leave it on private (as default) but set the DialogResult property of button1 on form 2 to "DialogResult OK" (under Properties > Behavior)*

**Form 1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        DialogResult res = frm.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            label1.Text = frm.MyNewText;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form 2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string MyNewText;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyNewText = textBox1.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! But can you explain the parts of using _parent and parent?

Comment: @AlvinTang added a second solution also. _parent is the instance of form 1 in this case so you can access all public properties.

Comment: Ah okay, got it, thanks. I prefer your first solution as I can understand it easier, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor of the forms you can get the values like this :

in form2 you should add a constructor like this :

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
    public string _newvalue
    public Form2(string value)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _newvalue=value
    }
//you should assign the value to the label .
}
```

in form1 you should do this :

```
form2 new=form2("sampletext");
new.showdialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

In Form1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2(this);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Codes in Form2:

```
        Form frm_;

        public Form2(Form frm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm_ = frm;
        }

        private void btnInForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)frm_.Controls.Find("lblInForm1", true)[0];

            string PassVal="What you want";
            lbl.Text = PassVal;
        }
```

Solution 2:

in Form 1:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    lblInForm1.Text = f.PassVal;
}
```

in Form 2:

```
internal string PassVal = "";
```

PassVal is a Field.