# How do i change the properties of a form from another form, C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some button that is identified with a specific tag, in Form3, whose background image I want to change from Form2. How do I do this, I tried:

```
foreach ( Button but in Bridge.Form3)
{
    if (but.Tag == tagcheck)
    {
        but.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.inactive;
    }
}
```

My project's name is Bridge, the image I want is in my resources named inactive. I get an error that under at the text Bridge.Form3

I tried then this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Form3.Controls )
{
     if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button) && ((Button)ctrl).Tag == tagcheck)
     {
         ((Button)ctrl).BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.inactive;
     }
}
```

I got the error message: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
Form 2 is already instantiated.

Comment: Don't you think it would help to share the error message? PS I think you want the `Controls` property of the form to `foreach` on, not the form itself.

Comment: If Form2 is instantiated afterwards, you can pass Form3 as a variable to it and then change it from there

Comment: In both cases you are using only class name not using object for accessing their members, and this is only happen in case of static class.
Hence for accessing any member of any class u need to make it either static or make an object of that class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending a value from opened form 2 to form 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969365/sending-a-value-from-opened-form-2-to-form-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//You have to fill this variable (e.g. in constructor) with a reference to the object of you form
public Form3 refF3;    

public void test() {
     foreach (Control ctrl in refF3.Controls) {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button) && ((Button)ctrl).Tag == tagcheck) {
                ((Button)ctrl).BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.inactive;
            {
      }
}
```

Comment: I get the error message: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: Oh, misread youe post and thougt Bridge.Form3 would be a reference... You need to replace `Bridge.Form3` with a reference to the Object of you form3

Comment: How do I do this, my instance of is named fm1

Comment: When and how do you initialize you Form3? Or how have you already used it?

Comment: I initialized it from a login form. After that I, from fm1 created form "Active", which on a click of a button has to change, among other things, the background image of button, with this indentifying tag, from fm1.

Comment: So if e.g you wrote `Form3 f3 = new Form3();` in your login form, you have to give `f3` to the form from which you want to change the button. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways of getting the object reference of a control located in a different form:

1- If you have to initialize the target form:

2- If the target form is already open

```
        Control.ControlCollection f3_ctrls;

        //Case 1
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();            
        f3.Show();
        f3_ctrls = f3.Controls;

        //Case 2
        f3_ctrls = (Application.OpenForms["Form3"]).Controls;

        foreach (Control ctrl in f3_ctrls)
        {
            if ((ctrl is Button) && ctrl.Tag.Equals("myTag"))
            {
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: One problem, I don't know my buttons name because it is created dynamically, I only have the information of its Tag property

Comment: @EdwardSnowden well, was it that hard?

Comment: Actually I don´t think this is the solution to his problem. I think he already has an object of Form3 where he wants to change the button properties but he isn´t verry familiar with objects so he don´t know how to access his instance of form3

Comment: @FatTony I'm sorry but I don't understand your point, his code most likely crashes because he did not instantiate Form3 correctly, which I show him how to do it with 2 different cases in my example, so how exactly did I not answer his question?

Comment: I understand, but when I check my form3, the "color" (in this case) of the button isn't changed expect when I closed my application and open it again. Help with this?

Comment: If creates an Object of Form3 in his main method for example and now he wants do change a button property of this intance of Form3 you code won´t work, because you´re creating a new object and chaning the properties in this new object, but not in the existing one

Comment: But since he stopped answering he either gave up, or has his problem solved

Comment: @EdwardSnowden you guys are not making any sense, or at least you are not communicating corretly...I have tested the code and it works well. As for FatTony's comment, In **case 1** yes, i am creating a new instance of the form, so if there was another one in use, that one wouldn't be affected by the changes, but that's where you want to use **case 2** instead. I have not given up, I'm just at work and try to reply in my spare time, try to be more respectful

Comment: Your efforts are very appreciated @Innat3